# How can I put a vertical scrollbar in extjs

Tags: extjs, scrollbar

I am using extjs to build a portal and I have the following problem. The images are more than the height of the tab (on the right size). What I want is to add a vertical scroll bar on this tab. How can I do this in extjs?

This is the part of my code:

```
   items: [{
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                activeTab: 0,
                flex: 2,
                items: [{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'Images',
                        items: [{contentEl:'img',autoScoll: true,height:11200,overflowY : String }]
                 },{    
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'Material',
                        items: [{contentEl:'msg',autoScoll: true,height:11200,overflowY : String }]
                        }]
            }]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see in your code `autoScoll` instead of `autoScroll: true`.
It seems to be a typo.
Check this out.

Comment: You were right. I feel stupid as I look at this 30 min already.  Is there something similar for the height? Like autoheight? Thanks.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you can use something like height:auto.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding layout:fit and autoScroll:true.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this -

```
overflowY: 'scroll'
```

Here's what it says in the documentation -

> 'scroll' to always enable vertical scrollbar (Style overflow-y:
>   'scroll').

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-overflowY

Answer (score 2):

For ExtJS 6 you can use [Ext.panel.Panel.scrollable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-scrollable).

To enable vertical scroll you can set it as `scrollable: 'vertical'`.

To force vertical scroll regardless of content you can pass [Ext.scroll.Scroller](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.scroll.Scroller.html#cfg-y) config:

```
scrollable: {
    y: 'scroll'
}
```